# stream_set_blocking php on windows

Tags: php

Why stream_set_blocking not works on windows..?

here some code that used stream_set_blocking

```
php -r "stream_set_blocking(STDIN, FALSE);echo fread(STDIN, 10);"
```

on linux it instantly exits. (correct behavior)

on windows it will hang for input. (incorrect behavior, it's ignoring the non blocking setting.)

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't seem to support it, according to the manual.

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-blocking
"On Windows, this has no affect on local files. Non-blocking IO for local files is not supported on Windows."